# How can I insert a sub-field while iterate on MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Suppose I iterate a mondodb items with pymongo as follows:

```
for item in client.db.collection.find(timeout=False):
...
```

How can I insert a new sub-field into item as I iterate through?
This is supposedly what I need to do

```
for item in client.db.collection.find(timeout=False):
        item['A'][0]['B'] = new_value
        item.save()
```

Comment: Is A an array? You want to replace the 0 indexed value or insert a new one?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking here. as @joao mentioned what is `A`, 'B'? why do you need `save`? Consider to improve your question by showing us your document and telling us what you are trying to achieve. Also I do believe that after 5 years here you should know [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1):

You can use update function.

$this->mongo->selectCollection($collectionName)->update(array('mlsnumber'=>$data['mlsnumber']),$data)